# Trigger send after submit from Smart Capture in Cloud Pages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, triggered-send

does anyone know if it is possible to trigger a send using a Smart Capture form in Cloud Pages?

I see this in the html tab:

```
    window.ScForm.init({"gearID":"fmgde7d9ecj","smartCaptureFormID":0,"sourceKey":"JB_Fac_Reactor","source":"dataExtension","triggeredSend":"","confirmationMessage":"Thank you for your submission.","buttonText":"Submit","buttonStyles":"","buttonAlign":"text-align: center","formStyling":""});
  };
```

Where it says "triggeredSend":"", I guess it should be possible to add a send definition. I have tried with the "customer key" of the send definition (which is the same as the definition name) but nothing happens.

Before troubleshooting more, does anyone know if triggered sends at all works yet (in Cloud pages)?

Thanks :-)

Comment: did you guys figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Triggered sends do work with Cloud Pages/Smart Capture. A popular use case is "welcome" signup emails after form submit. However, the form needs to be built using the "classic" landing page form tools rather than content builder microsite tools in order to allow a triggered send; but apparently SFMC is working on enhancing this to support the Content Builder tools eventually.

You need to create a triggered send data extension (using a triggered send DE template first), and then you should be able to select that trigger DE in the dropdown when configuring your form actions.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two work around. 1) you use List and then use the "Welcome email" feature to send out emails.
2) Use JB's feature called "Smart Capture/Cloud Pages" - however this has its own set of limitations.

Answer (score -1):

Cloud pages are useless if they cant perform this simple task. Currently I use automation studio and run a script to send and email.

Another solution would be to have the thank you page go to a page that has AMP capability, and then use AMP to fire the email.